# Where i can get InstallCleanup.exe for Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, uninstallation, visual-studio-2022

I tried to install additonal packages via Visual Studio 2022 module manager. During downloading it stopped and said that can’t download some files. I asked it firstly to retry to download, then after insuccesfull attempt i asked it to pass. But updating crashed and Visual Studio became unavailable. I found the only way to uninstall it, but it had not unistalled properly. It was my fault to delete all directories of MS Visual Studio in system folders via Shift+Delete.

Now i try vs_community.exe and VisualStudioInstaller, they are both run bootstrapper that firstly ask my administrator rigths, then ask informed consent, then it starts to download but nothing happens - for an arbitrary long time it stays on 0 bytes and 0%.
In the Internet i have found a way to solve it trough InstallCleanup.exe, but this file does not exist on my PC too.

That information i sent to MS Support and wait an answer.

UPD 06.11.2022: Good day everybody. Today i have tried to use a Kaspersky Secure Connection. And visual studio bootstrapper started succesfully and began downloading. But after it have drained free traffic of KSC (300 MB) downloading stopped. So I think the cause of abovementioned problem is some kind of blocking, maybe by Roscomnadzor, maybe by Microsoft.
Thank you for assistance. IMHO this case might be closed as solved.